# ¿Cómo puedo mostrar datos en una tabla y luego borrar los registros por separado utilizando php?

Tags: php, sql, delete

necesito ayuda , estoy bastante atascado .

[image: foro]

En la primera parte creo el código necesario para que me devuelva los campos de las tablas y su resultado . Parece que he conseguido de momento crear un enlace por cada registro que parece funcionar a primera vista ,hacia la página que se va a encargar de realizar el borrado de registro :

```
!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<CENTER>
<h1> CAMPO ARQUEOLÓGICO </h1>

<?php 
$host = "localhost";
$user = "bt";
$pwd = "bt";
$bd = "db_23_CTra_J";

if (!$conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $bd))

{    
    exit("No se pudo realizar la conexión."); 
}

else

{
// LANZAMOS NUESTRA CONSULTA PARA MOSTRAR DATOS DE LA BBDD

$consulta = "SELECT * FROM t_22_CTrab_Reser";
$res = mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta);

}
?>

<table border='3' cellpadding='7' cellspacing='6'><tr><th colspan='7'>RESERVAS CAM J.R</th></tr><tr><th>DNI</th><th>NOMBRE</th><th>APELLIDO</th><th>TELEFONO</th><th>ACTIVIDAD</th><th>ALOJAMIENTO</th></tr>

<?php
/*
* Utilizo la condicion while 
*/
while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($res,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
?>

<tr>
<td><form action="borrar.php" method="post"><?php echo $fila['Dni'];?></form></td>
<td><?php echo $fila['Nombre'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $fila['Apellido'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $fila['telefono'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $fila['Actividad'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $fila['Alojamiento'];?></td>
<td><a href="borrar.php?dni = <?php echo $fila['Dni'];?>">BORRAR</a></td>
</tr>

<?php
}
mysqli_free_result($res);
mysqli_close($conexion);
?>

</table>
<?php 
echo "<br/>La consulta se ha realizado con éxito<br/>";
echo "<br/><button onclick=location.href='http://localhost/evaluativa3/PRINCIPAL.php'> Regresa ,al formulario principal</button><br/>";
?>

</CENTER>
</body>
</html>
```

[![tabla][2]][2]

En la segunda parte del proyecto donde meto el código para que recoja las peticiones de borrado de los registros por separado me lanza este error :

**Warning: Undefined array key "Dni" in C:\xampp\htdocs\evaluativa3\borrar.php on line 14
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_query() in C:\xampp\htdocs\evaluativa3\borrar.php:17 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\evaluativa3\borrar.php on line 17**

```
<?php

$host = "localhost";
$user = "bt";
$pwd = "bt";
$bd = "db_";

if (!$conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $bd))
{
    exit("No se pudo realizar la conexión.");
}

        // Traspasamos a una variable local para evitar problemas con las comillas:
        $Dni = $_POST['Dni'];
        $consulta = "DELETE FROM t_22_CTrab_Reser WHERE Dni='$Dni'";
        
        if (mysql_query($conexion, $consulta))
        {
            echo "<p>Registro eliminado.</p>";
        } 
        else
        {
            echo "<p>No se puede eliminar </p>";
        

    echo '<p>Regresar al <a href="modificar.php">registro </a></p>';
    
    mysqli_close($conexion);
}
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En PHP las claves de array son *case sensitive*, es decir, sensibles a mayúsculas y minúsculas.

Al llamar a `borrar.php` le estás pasando `dni`, me refiero a esta fila (lo que importa es lo que hay justo después de `?`):

```
<td><a href="borrar.php?dni = <?php echo $fila['Dni'];?>">BORRAR</a></td>
```

Y luego, lo estás buscando como `Dni` en la superglobal `$_POST`:

```
$Dni = $_POST['Dni'];
```

Por eso estás teniendo el *`Undefined array key "Dni"`*.

Debes ponerlo tal y como lo estás pasando:

```
$Dni = $_POST['dni'];
```

Pero hay otros errores en tu código:

- Nunca deberías ir a buscar un valor en la superglobal sin antes verificar que existe.
- Esto `dni = <?php echo $fila['Dni']` podría hacer que se cuelen espacios en blanco antes / después del valor, evítalo, poniendo las cosas sin espacios y además, usa `trim()` al recuperar el dato.
- Estás usando `mysql_query` en vez de `mysqli_query`.
- La forma real de saber si se eliminaron registros es verificando con `mysqli_affected_rows()`
- Estás cerrando la conexión en la parte del `else`

Corrijamos todo:

#### HTML

Quita los espacios en blanco:

```
<td><a href="borrar.php?dni=<?php echo $fila['Dni'];?>">BORRAR</a></td>
```

#### PHP

```
<?php

    $host = "localhost";
    $user = "bt";
    $pwd = "bt";
    $bd = "db_";
    
    if (!$conexion = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $pwd, $bd))
    {
        exit("No se pudo realizar la conexión.");
    }

    /*
       Usaré fusión de null para verificar que hay datos
       Si usas PHP anterior a 7 cambia la línea siguiente por esto:
       $Dni = !empty($_POST['dni']) ? trim($_POST['dni']) : NULL;
    */
    $Dni = trim($_POST['dni']) ?? NULL;
    if (!$Dni) {
        exit('No hay ningún valor para el DNI');
    }
    $consulta = "DELETE FROM t_22_CTrab_Reser WHERE Dni='$Dni'";       
    if (mysqli_query($conexion, $consulta))
    {
        printf("<p>Registros eliminados: %d.</p>", mysqli_affected_rows($conexion));
    } 
    else
    {
        echo "<p>No se puede eliminar </p>";
        echo '<p>Regresar al <a href="modificar.php">registro </a></p>';
    }
    mysqli_close($conexion);
?>
```

Comment: Efectivamente,me ha servido de gran ayuda tu respuesta . Muchas gracias por ser tan atento